# ¿Qué significa "gato" como insulto en Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, argentina, animales, lenguaje-peyorativo

He oído en Argentina llamar a un político "gato" como insulto.

¿Qué significados peyorativos tiene la palabra "gato" en Argentina?
¿Hay alguno que pueda ser usado como insulto especialmente hacia un político?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según [este artículo](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/2004576-de-donde-viene-y-que-significa-el-insulto-gato), el uso de la palabra 'gato' como insulto en Argentina tiene varias historias.

El primer uso tiene su raíz en el lunfardo. El verbo 'gatillar' significa "pagar lo necesario para invitar a las *vedettes* porteñas". Un gato, entonces, es alguien que gatilla.

El segundo significado, que vino luego, es "mujer que acepta las invitaciones de los (hombres) gatos".

Como final, también significa alguien que sirve a otros, un uso que se supone nació en la cárcel.

Aplicado a un político, podría valer cualquiera de los tres significados o incluso una mezcla de los tres: el primero en el sentido de que gasta el dinero en vicios; el segundo en el sentido de que se "prostituye", es decir que se vende a otros agentes políticos; y el tercero en el sentido de que sirve a otras personas o intereses de los que debería.

Comment: El artículo citado termina con "¿Cuál de estas acepciones es la que se usa hoy? Para Oscar Conde, "**el uso popular que se le da ahora es el de simple insulto.** Cuando alguien le dice 'gato' a otro simplemente lo quiere denigrar, llamar sirviente. No tiene que ver con el viejo uso, con el que 'gatilla'. Es sólo una apropiación más abstracta, sacada de contexto, del uso tumbero del término".

Comment: Parece que la inmigración francesa en Argentina fue una de las más numerosas, y en francés `chatte` tiene connotaciones vulgares. A lo mejor los franceses tuvieron algo que ver en el origen del "gato" como insulto.

Comment: El primer significado se usa también como mujeriego?

Answer (score 2):

Gato en el norte argentino significa también ladrón. "Sos un gato" significa sos ladrón cuando es un uso en ese sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Gato o gata, tiene muchas formas dependiendo de a quien se lo digas y la intención con que se haga.

Varios ejemplos.

- Que te digan, "*dos tremendo gato o gata*", es cuando un pibe que anda con todas las minas o mujeres, en el caso de las mujeres es que anda con todos los pibes o hombres.
- Otro caso del mismo dicho es que es una puta o un "*maricón*".
- Otro es que "*sos un gato*" que "*sos un rastrillo*" o ladrón.
- Si te dicen, *mira esa gata* depende, porque puede decir mira esa mina(mujer) o mira esa perra.
- El insulto también comúnmente es, "*mira ese gato barato*", es que es una puta barata o un puto(maricón) de mierda.
- Otro es, que pinto gato es vamos a la pista (significa buscas pelear salame?)

Y muchos más, *tenés* que vivir en Argentina para sacar bien las formas y se dice en confianza, porque si SOS un gallego, y le decís gato a uno o gata a una, terminas en la pista peleando con los puños.